# Speed up HDMI connection on ubuntu 20.04?

Tags: multiple-monitors

So I use ubuntu 20.04 on my laptop with external monitor, I use basic HDMI cable ~ not the golden expensive one. Everytime my computer goes to sleep mode, witch make my external monitor goes to sleep/black screen too, when I press a key my laptop woken up fast, but my monitor will take roughly 2 seconds, witch is annoy me so much.

Is there any thing that I could do to speed up my HDMI connection? Should I go buy some expensive cable? Is it helping?

Note that I use cheap monitor 24" Phillips IPS ($150)

Comment: No and a different cable won't change anything. This is how the monitor works.

Comment: Thanks, you should write an answer for that and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Someone in the comments already said it: that the cable quality is not going to help it's that the monitor is just taking time to wake back up.

You could consider setting your laptop to take a bit longer to blank out / shut off the monitor - I don't have an Ubuntu desktop sitting right in front of me at the moment (I mostly use server) but I'm sure there's a setting

The other thing you can look at is to poke at your monitor - it may be possible to have it not shut down/sleep when it gets no signal - this would use more electricity but if things are just timing out a bit too quickly, it could help

EDIT: corrected "big longer" to "bit longer"